# Meaning of words in /etc/login.defs

Tags: 18.04, security, configuration, etc

Community!

After printing `/etc/login.defs`, I've encountered such magic numbers like **#290803** and **#298773**. I guess they refer some documentation about security risks, but where I can find it?

Fragment:

```
# Enable display of unknown usernames when login failures are recorded.
#
# WARNING: Unknown usernames may become world readable. 
# See #290803 and #298773 for details about how this could become a security
# concern
LOG_UNKFAIL_ENAB        no
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find out which package provides `/etc/login.defs` with

```
dpkg -S /etc/login.defs
```

and then

```
apt-get changelog <packagename>
```

will show the change log for the package. It will have some information.

A simple internet search for "login.defs 298773" led me to  https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=298773 and, by logical extension,

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=290803

Comment: Using this approach I've found reference only to one of two - #298773, and it was something like **Close: #blabla**. Could you please tell what these numbers actually tell us, where they appear except changelogs, and so on?

Comment: A simple internet search for "login.defs 298773" led me to https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=298773